# Update version Hibernate Jboss Ejb and Java

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, jboss

I have one aplication that use EJB 2, Hibernate 2, Java 1.4 and Jboss 4.0.1.
I would like to start one update of these versions.
But where do I begin?
Can start whith EJB 2 to EJB 3? 
Or I do whith Hibernate 2 to Hibernate 4? 
Or can I begin with Java version 1.4 to 1.8 or 1.7?
There is some documentation to help me?
Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: That's a fairly complex migration. I don't think you're going to find a road map to cover all the steps.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first thing you should ask yourself: why am I gonna need this improvement? Start thinking about the functionality: touching a business application which is working fine just for the sake of updating libraries/java version most of the time is a suicidal path.

Example: you need an updated library version of Hibernate for better stored procedure support? Start from that, find the version which grant the feature YOU NEED closest to do the minimal upgrading effort and then upgrade all other things to make it run. Nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 0):

Does your app uses any JBoss 4 specific features? 
- Look for org.jboss.* imports.
- Are the hibernate classes and *.hbm.xml files packed in a HAR file?

If yes you must migrate this first.
If not then try to deploy your EAR or WAR file to the newest version of Wildfly.

If you encounter any problems come back with more specific questions.